# RStudio and Shiny: messages between server and client

Tags: java, html, r, rstudio, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny application, and I need the messages that the client sends to the server and the answers the server sends back (especially the images).  The problem is t I don't know how they communicate with each other. I was trying to get this information from the documentation, but I wasn't able to find it. I would prefer to get these server-client messages in Java, but I'm interested in any solution that can work.

This is how I would like my app to work:

We have shiny code which generates a  web page that contains an image and a few things the user can change. Whenever the user changes something (a check-box, menu, etc), the current state of the page should be saved. Alternatively, we could have a a button that the user clicks to save the state of the page. We would like to save the  whole html, or just the image. with the current state of the menus as a string. I tried to save the html, but it did not contain the image. That is why I would like t those messages, because I guess they contain the data I need.

However, I chose Java, because these states should be saved to a graph showing step-by-step how the final form gained shape. I would prefer to save this into an Xmind workbook as it  has a nice Java API, which I could use to make the needed workbook.

Comment: Hey, This is exactly what i want to do, except the img.  how you save your current state of the page?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
options(shiny.trace=TRUE)
runApp("myApp")
```

The messages between the server and the ui are then printed in the R console. see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002712/shiny-what-is-the-option-setting-to-display-in-the-console-the-messages-between/23031361#23031361). Hope this will help.