# Shiny: What is the option setting to display in the console the messages between server and ui

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I remember having used an option setting that enable to print in the R console the messages between the server and ui while a shiny app is running.
This option is really useful to understand what is happening in the app.
However I cant remember the name of that option and can not find it anymore in the documentation.
Can someone can tell what is that option ?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like `print` or `cat`? Or `browser()`, which stops the execution and opens a browser environment? Check also the [debugging Shiny lesson](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/lessons/Lesson-10/)

Comment: No. That's an option were all the messages between the ui and server are printed on the R console. For example if you change the value in one widget of the interface, then the interface send a message to the server that this value has changed. That's really different from the functions that are described in the debugging Shiny lesson. That's apparently an undocumented feature and I can not remember where I found it originally. If I remeber well this was set up by a call to `options()`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I finally found it :

```
options(shiny.trace=TRUE)
```

Before running the app. I find it extremely useful to understand what is appending. I don't know why it is not more documented.

Comment: Why this is so hard to find?! Debugging shiny is a nightmare, thanks for pointing this one!

Comment: How do you make this work when you are hosting the shiny app remotely? Where do you make the call to options()?

Answer (score 1):

R Studio lists a nice summary of R Shiny global options available [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/shiny-options.html)

You may wish to turn both of these on:

        `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)
        options(shiny.fullstacktrace=TRUE)`